# Active Admin : triggering a modal window from a click on an action_item link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have that action_item on my admin page:

```
action_item :only => :index do
    link_to I18n.t('admin.dem_ref_nvl_etb'), :action => 'whatever'
  end
```

I'd like to know how I could display a pop-up window by clicking that link above, pretty much just like batch_action does when you use it with a "form" option (I don't need such an action here, it's just a basic link).

Any hint ?

Thanks a million for reading and helping!

Answer (score 10):

Building on Hugues's answer, here's a more fleshed-out example that I managed to cobble together with my very meager javascript skills:

In `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`:

```
//= require active_admin/base

$(document).on('ready page:load turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('a.lextest').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();  // prevent Rails UJS click event
    e.preventDefault();

    ActiveAdmin.modal_dialog("Send email to: ", {emails: 'text'}, function(inputs) {alert (inputs.emails)})
  })
})
```

Note that I don't use the default `active_admin.js.coffee` because I dislike coffeescript -- just a personal preference.  This code adds an onClick event handler to all links with class `lextest`.  Now you can create such a link with a link_to:

`link_to('Modal', '#', class: 'lextest')`

I cobbled this all together from the way `batch_action` is [implemented](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/lib/batch_actions.js.coffee#L6).

Comment: Full example including round-tripping data back into rails: https://github.com/heroku/retrodot/pull/28/files

Answer (score 4):

I found out your answer to your question. I won't go into much details as I suppose you know your Javascript, but this could be expand further.

ActiveAdmin come with a modal dialog javascript library. It is quite crude, but can get the job done. You can read about its existance on this documentation page:
http://activeadmin.info/docs/9-batch-actions.html 
toward the 3/4 down at the end of the Batch Action form section.
For the exact code check github:
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/lib/modal_dialog.js.coffee

And this is a very basic example you can copy paste in a javascript console to check the effect.

```
ActiveAdmin.modal_dialog("Send email to: ", {emails: 'text'}, function(inputs) {alert (inputs.emails)})
```

As long as your good with your Javascript skills, you should be on track.

Comment: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/3dcb1834620f38f73ac5c1f550f37986d486f29c/app/javascript/active_admin/lib/modal-dialog.js

Comment: https://activeadmin.info/9-batch-actions.html

Comment: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/app/javascript/active_admin/lib/modal-dialog.js